# Trying to make my partial work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to iterate through two sets of values on the same web page so I wrote a partial to eliminate duplicate code. The two variables that I am trying to iterate through are `@bookmarks` and `@liked_bookmarks`.

The partial is rendered properly if I use either `@bookmarks` or `@liked_bookmarks` in the partial it's self but then the only one of the value sets are displayed. in the code below I tried using `@resource` as a stand in that will have `@bookmarks` and `@liked_bookmarks` passed into it.

this is the partial that is located in `app/views/bookmarks/_bookmarksandlikes.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <% @resource.each do |x| %>
    <%= x.url%>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

and this is the code for the page that I am calling the above partial on located in `app/views/users/show.html.erb`

```
<h1>My Blocmarks</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/show.html.erb</p>

<div>
  <h1>Blockmarks I have created  </h1>
  <div class =row>
     <%= render partial: 'bookmarks/bookmarksandlikes', locals: { topic:     @bookmarks} %>
   </div>

</div>


<div>
  <h1>Blockmarks I have liked
    <%= render partial: 'bookmarks/bookmarksandlikes', locals: { topic:     @liked_bookmarks} %>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close. Instead of `@resource` just use `topic`, which you are passing in as a local.

```
<div>
  <% topic.each do |x| %>
    <%= x.url%>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Since you are not passing @resource into partial and passing only topic variable you need to do it**

```
<div>
<% topic.each do |x| %>
<%= x.url%>
<% end %>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<div>
  <% @resource.each do |x| %>
    <%= x.url%>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

Do it:

```
<div>
  <% topic.each do |x| %>
    <%= x.url%>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

Because you pass the object on `locals: { topic:     @liked_bookmarks}` you should use `topic` instead of using any `instance that is not initialize`.